# Iterate through points in an arbitrary shape

Tags: c++, math, iteration, shapes, multimap

I've a multimap of points `multimap<int,int>` which surrounds (gapless) an arbitrary shape (a land area to be specific). How would I iterate through all points contained in the arbitrary shape?

I know that the multimap is not enough to determine the interior points, therefore I've got an additional point, that's inside of the shape (to determine inner and outer of the shape).

Further information: The points are sorted x-wise because multimap is a sorted container. All points are located in a grid, because I'm using bitmaps.

Comment: are you working on a lattice ? Are the points in the multimap in a particular order ? Is the shape convex ?

Comment: Yea it's on a lattice. It's an image so it has a pixel-lattice. The points are sorted x-wise. The shap can't be convex in a lattice right?

Comment: @Backfighter You can reinterpret the meaning of "convex" in the context of lattice points. In particular, since your boundary points are x-sorted, maybe you can look at all y-values between (x,y0) at the bottom boundary and (x,y1) at the top boundary. Convex in this case could mean that all (x,y) are in the shape where y0<y<y1, which gives a way to iterate through the interior points. If it's not convex, then things will be a little more complicated, but still manageable I think.

Comment: @Edward Doolittle In this case it's not convex at all the shap is completely random as provided by the user.
The problem is how do I know if a y-value is a top or a bottom boundry?

Comment: Try starting below the region and working up. If you hit a boundary point, points above will be in the region until you hit another boundary point, when they'll be outside of the region, until you hit another boundary point, when they'll be inside the region ... . You have to be careful that your region is not exactly one pixel wide at any location, though; or if it is, then the same point could be in the list twice, once as a lower boundary and once as an upper boundary.

Comment: @Edward Doolittle but what if the shap goes "out" of the images boundry. If it for example starts at y0 = 10 and ends at y1 = 900 (if you hit 0 you start over at e.g. 950).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but maybe including the image boundary as part of the shape boundary would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your points are farther apart than 1 pixel, then Points sorted by x coordinate are not going to be very helpful. Sort them such that points which should be connected are next to each other.
2. [Draw lines between the points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)
3. Find a point thats inside and [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) the shape. If you implement it yourself, you need to iterate over every pixel inside the shape for that.

Answer (score 1):

One test for the whether a point is in the interior/exterior of a shape is to imagine a ray from that point to a point which is known to be outside the the shape. Count the number of times which the ray crosses the boundary, if this number is odd then the point is inside the shape, if its even than the point is outside the shape. See [ray casting algorithm for a point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).

In your case it will be easiest to take a vertical ray which has the same x-value as you test point, `(x0,y0)` say. Let `(x0,y1)` be some point outside the bounding box of your shape. Simply count the number of points in the multimap with the same x value. If its odd you are inside, if its even you are outside.

The above assumes some details about your shape boundary: the complete boundary of the shape is included, so if the shape crosses edge of your image points on the edge are included in the multimap, also you don't have two adjacent points so `(x,y)`, and `(x,y+1)` are not both in the multimap.